# SVG use xlink buggy click event

Tags: javascript, html, events, svg, dom-events

I am using https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-svgstore to compile multiple SVGs into a single one and use them with:

```
<svg id="button"><use xlink:href="#svg-test"></use></svg>
```

I style it with CSS (width, height, fill, etc).

The problem is when I want to attach javascript event, for example a click.
The problem does not exist on Firefox, all other browsers have hard time handling the event.
It works, sometimes.

In the pen that I have here it doesn't work at all: http://codepen.io/IvanDokov/pen/IcvbB

I saw that CodePen use the same technology and they have button as wrapper for the svg and div. The div is absolutely positioned over the svg and actually you cannot click the svg and the events work properly.

Is there a way to not hack it like this. I don't want one extra wrapper and a div inside it.

Comment: It seems to work if you add an `$("#svg").click` event.

Comment: Looks like a jQuery only problem to me - [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13180) with [this change](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1130) looks suspicious: "Black-hole SVG <use> instance trees". When you debug, you see that in this code piece the registered handler is ignored.

Comment: That's really weird, but it's true. Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.